# Using variables inside json file

Tags: python, json

I need to define a variable once and use it throughout the json file.

Here is my MWE: (adapted from [here](http://www.packer.io/docs/templates/user-variables.html))

```
{
  "variables": {
    "my_access_key": "abc",
    "my_secret_key": "def"
  },
  "objectB": {
    "type": "1",
    "access_key": "{{user `my_access_key`}}",
    "secret_key": "{{user `my_secret_key`}}"
  },
  "objectA": {
    "type": "2",
    "access_key": "{{user `my_access_key`}}",
    "secret_key": "{{user `my_secret_key`}}"
  }
}
```

The `access_key` field of the objects `objectB` and `objectA` must be equal to "`abc`", which  is defined by me in the beginning of the file.

How can I achieve this goal in python?

Comment: You cant use variables in JSON file. What is the purpose of this JSON file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## JSON does not allow variable referencing

In YAML, you may define variables, set reference names for them and then reuse them later on in the file.

JSON does not provide this sort of functionality, you have to set these values yourself place by place.

## JSON built programmatically

```
import json

access = "AAA"
secret = "XXX"

dct = {"variables": {"my_access_key": access, "my_secret_key": secret},
       "objectB": {"type": "1", "access_key": access, "secret_key": secret},
       "objectA": {"type": "2", "access_key": access, "secret_key": secret}
      }
json_str = json.dumps(dct, indent=True)
print json_str
```

what prints

```
{
 "objectA": {
  "access_key": "AAA", 
  "secret_key": "XXX", 
  "type": "2"
 }, 
 "variables": {
  "my_secret_key": "XXX", 
  "my_access_key": "AAA"
 }, 
 "objectB": {
  "access_key": "AAA", 
  "secret_key": "XXX", 
  "type": "1"
 }
}
```

## Use YAML anchors and references

You might use YAML feature for this purpose. As YAML is rather easy to edit, it could be good option for config files.

Before you use it, be sure, you install pyyaml:

```
$ pip install pyyaml
```

Then the code (with modified names in `variables` to fit our needs):

```
import json
import yaml
yaml_str = """
variables: &keys
    access_key: abc
    secret_key: def
objectB:
    <<: *keys
    type: "1"
objectA:
    <<: *keys
    type: "2"
"""

dct = yaml.load(yaml_str)
json_str = json.dumps(dct, indent=True)
print json_str
```

which prints

```
{
 "objectA": {
  "access_key": "abc", 
  "secret_key": "def", 
  "type": "2"
 }, 
 "variables": {
  "access_key": "abc", 
  "secret_key": "def"
 }, 
 "objectB": {
  "access_key": "abc", 
  "secret_key": "def", 
  "type": "1"
 }
}
```