# Possible to pass Variable to angular.json and avoid code duplication?

Tags: json, angular, angular-cli

I am looking for a way to pass information to `angular.json` file so that I do not need to repeat build configurations and avoid all the code duplication. I can not explain well so I'll try with an example. So In my `angular.json`under `configurations` I have something like

```
"configurations": {
"de": {
              "aot": true,
              "i18nLocale": "de",
              "i18nFile": "project/src/locale/messages.de.xlf",
              "i18nFormat": "xlf"
            },
            "en-gb": {
              "aot": true,
              "i18nLocale": "en-gb",
              "i18nFile": "project/src/locale/messages.en-gb.xlf",
              "i18nFormat": "xlf"
            },
            "en-us": {
              "aot": true,
              "i18nLocale": "en-us",
              "i18nFile": "project/src/locale/messages.en-us.xlf",
              "i18nFormat": "xlf"
            },
            "es": {
              "aot": true,
              "i18nLocale": "es",
              "i18nFile": "project/src/locale/messages.es.xlf",
              "i18nFormat": "xlf"
            },
            "fr": {
              "aot": true,
              "i18nLocale": "fr",
              "i18nFile": "project/src/locale/messages.fr.xlf",
              "i18nFormat": "xlf"
            },
            "it": {
              "aot": true,
              "i18nLocale": "it",
              "i18nFile": "project/src/locale/messages.it.xlf",
              "i18nFormat": "xlf"
            },
            "pt-br": {
              "aot": true,
              "i18nLocale": "pt-br",
              "i18nFile": "project/src/locale/messages.pt-br.xlf",
              "i18nFormat": "xlf"
            }
```

Is there a way to have a variable like lets say `i18n` and I can use it in `angular.json` like `$i18n` :

```
"configurations": {
"i18n": {
              "aot": true,
              "i18nLocale": "$i18n",
              "i18nFile": "project/src/locale/messages.$i18n.xlf",
              "i18nFormat": "xlf"
            }
```

I am not good with english. I hope I explained well using the example for what I am looking for. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't have this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23869882/using-variables-inside-json-file

Comment: this makes me so sad, thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't speak *angular*, but in the hope this is useful, I think you're looking at this something like this:

```
echo '["de","en-gb","en-us","es","fr","it"]' | jq '
  {"configuration":[ .[] as $c |
    {
      ($c):{
         "aot":true,
         "i18nLocale": $c,
         "i18nFile": ("project/src/locale/messages." + $c + ".xlf"),
         "i18nFormat": "xlf"
      }
    }
  ]}'
```

This command uses [jq command line parser](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to forge a JSON configuration according to your first example.

You can grow the table sent by `echo` to `jq` to any country string and get as many configurations.