# How can I use variables in json file?

Tags: json

There is a value that is used several times in a json file.

I want to make this value as a variable, and want the variable to be used instead of inserting string each time.

```
  "DOCKER_IMAGE": "registry.somewhere.com:tag",
  "components":[
    {
      "name": "component_1",
      "docker_image": $DOCKER_IMAGE
      ...
    },
    {
      "name": "component_2",
      "docker_image": $DOCKER_IMAGE
      ...
    }
```

Something like this.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What language are you using? Javascript?

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23869882/using-variables-inside-json-file

Comment: @PhanNhậtHuy I'm using this json file for a Yarn Service.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, you cannot do this in regular JSON. A possible workaround is to put placeholder text where you want the "variable" to be filled in, then globally replace it before decoding the JSON string.